# Trying to add an item to Wordpress primary menu using wp_nav_menu_items does not work

Tags: php, wordpress

I am building a website using WordPress with a user profile section. I built a 'primary' navigation using the following code:

`

```
<!-- The WordPress Menu goes here -->
                <?php wp_nav_menu(
                    array(
                        'theme_location'  => 'primary',
                        'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                        'container_id'    => 'navbarNavDropdown',
                        'menu_class'      => 'navbar-nav ml-auto',
                        'fallback_cb'     => '',
                        'menu_id'         => 'main-menu',
                        'depth'           => 2,
                        'walker'          => new Understrap_WP_Bootstrap_Navwalker(),
                    )
                ); ?>
```

`

Using the 'wp_nav_menu_items' filter, I am trying to add a custom link as item to this menu with the following code:

`

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'your_custom_menu_item',10,2);
                    function your_custom_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {
                     if ($args->theme_location == 'primary') {
                            $items.="<li>Testing Menu</li>";
                            return $items;
                    }
                }
```

`

However it does not appear in the menu.

Does any of you guys have an idea what I am doing wrong here?

Hope to hear from you soon!

Cheers,

Hans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was just working on a similar problem yesterday, although I am targeting a specific menu item that is added via the Admin interface - and injecting new items based off an parsed xml data. Here's the code if it helps... (main thing is returning $menu_items after adding new items - but also using this method, you do no have to wrap the element - let the WP core handle that for you.)

```
class TFDC_Menu_Markets {

    function __construct() {
        add_filter( 'wp_get_nav_menu_items', array($this, 'add_menu_items'), 20,2);
    }

    function add_menu_items( $menu_items, $menu){
        global $tfdc;
        $widget_menu = false;
        foreach( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
            if( array_intersect( array( 'tfdc-menu' ), $menu_item->classes ) ){
                $widget_menu = $menu_item;
                break;
            }
        }

        if( ! $widget_menu )
            return false;

        $index=0;
        foreach($tfdc->markets as $marketID=>$marketLongName) {
            $index++;
            $menu_items[] = $this->add_item($marketLongName,'/widgets/view/?marketID='.$marketID,$widget_menu->ID,$index);
        }

        return $menu_items;

    }

    function add_item($title, $url, $parent, $order=0) {
        $item = new stdClass();
        $item->ID = 1000000 + $order + $parent;
        $item->title = $title;
        $item->url = $url;
        $item->menu_item_parent = $parent;
        $item->menu_order = $parent + $order;

        return $item;
    }

}

$menu_markets = new TFDC_Menu_Markets();
```